# JavaScript write a cookie with expiration time

Tags: javascript, unix, cookies, timestamp

Im trying to get a cookie written through javascript with an expire time of 30 minutes.  I've followed many threads on stack and other websites, and I have a code I believe should be working, but the cookie isn't writing.

```
<script>
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(30*60*1000));
    var expires = date.toGMTString();
    var offset= -d.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
    document.cookie = 'timezone='+offset+';expires='+expires+';path=/';
</script>
```

Any idea why this isnt working? the oddest thing, i had the cookie writing earlier, but i couldn't get the expire time to work properly, and now i can't get it to write at all! Im almost certain I changed my code back to what was originally working (without the expire time) but now i cant get it to go at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `-d.getTimezoneOffset()`?

Comment: ^ that is the offset from GMT, this is a script for setting the users timezone, that has been working properly, when the cookie was actually writing.

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/hsmPY/2/

Comment: No, what is `-d`? Where is it declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using some `d` variable here that is not defined and you are getting a javascript error (did you look in your javascript console by the way?):

```
var offset= -d.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
```

You probably meant:

```
var offset= -date.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
```

as your variable is called `date`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, yeah, that's exactly what I am saying in my answer.

Comment: I know; I'm just posting fiddles that demo that. I gave you a vote. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
    <script>
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(30*60*1000));
    var expires = date.toGMTString();
    var offset= -date.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
    document.cookie = 'timezone='+offset+';expires='+expires+';path=/';
</script>
```